# String-parsing-fu: Can you help me find a way to retrieve this value?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I need to somehow detect if there *is* a parent OU value, and if there is retrieve it.

For example, here there is no parent:

```
LDAP://servera/OU=Santa Cruz,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

But here, there is a parent:

```
LDAP://servera/OU=Ventas,OU=Santa Cruz,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

So I would need to retrieve that "Ventas" string.

Another example:

```
LDAP://servera/OU=Contabilidad,OU=Ventas,OU=Santa Cruz,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

I would need to retrieve that "Ventas" string **as well**.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: I assume the answer needs to work for any LDAP URL that someone might come up with?  So, OU may not be the first attribute in the list, its value may contain '\,', etc.?  I think the answers so far (mine included) work for your examples, but may not work for everything you will need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd find the first occurrence of `OU=...` and get it's value.  Then I'd check if there was another occurrence after it.  If so, return the value I've got.  If not, return whatever it is you want if there's no parent (`String.Empty`, or, `null`, or whatever).

You could also use a regular express like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"OU=(.*?),");
var matches = regex.Matches(ldapString);
```

Then check how many matches there are.  If >1 return the captured value from the first match.

**Update**

The regex above needs to be improved to allow the case where there's an escaped comma (`\,`) in the LDAP string.  Maybe something like:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"OU=((.*?(\\\,)+?)+?),");
```

That may be broken, and there may be simpler way to do the same thing.  I'm not a regex wizard.

**Another Update**

Per Kimberly's comment below the regex should be `@"OU=((?:.*?(?:\\\,)*?)+?),"`.

Comment: Getting warmer!  I think it needs to be this: @"OU=((?:.*?(?:\\\,)*?)+?),".  This returns a single group per match, allowing the logic you originally described to apply, provided you adjust it to 'return the .Groups[1] from the second-to-last match'.  I tested it somewhat obsessively here: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7ebcb70b-e3b7-43b3-b660-52f429ebfe50

Comment: Also, I'm sorry for causing confusion with my comment earlier. I thought I deleted it fast enough, but then there was some downtime so who knows what happened.

Comment: @Kimberly: Thanks.  I've added your update to my answer.  If my answer get accepted I'll give you half the points  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
string ldap = "LDAP://servera/OU=Ventas,OU=Santa Cruz,DC=contoso,DC=com";
Match match = Regex.Match(ldap, @"LDAP://\w+/OU=(?<toplevelou>\w+?),OU=");
if(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Result("${toplevelou}"));
}
```

Comment: \w+ will not match if 'Santa Cruz' is the parent OU and 'Ventas' is the child.  Edit, eh, for that matter, mine will not match 'Washington, DC'.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: You can use \s+ instead of \w+ or [^,] as in your edited example.

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but I 'd do it this way (hey ma, look, an one-liner!):

```
var str = "LDAP://servera/OU=Ventas,OU=Santa Cruz,DC=contoso,DC=com";
var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Split(',')
                .Select(s => s.Split('='))
                .Where(a => a[0] == "OU")
                .Select(a => a[1])
                .Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

`result` is either `null` or has the string you want. **This will work no matter how many `OU`s are in there** and return the second-to-last one, as long as the format of the string is valid to begin with.

**Update: possible improvements:**

The above will not work correctly if your DN contains an escaped forward slash or an escaped comma.

To fix both of these you need to use regular expressions. Change:

```
str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Split(',')
```

to:

```
Regex.Split(Regex.Split(str, "(?<!\\\\)/").Last(), "(?<!\\\\),")
```

What this does is separate the DN by getting the last part of `str` after splitting on forward slashes, and split the in parts DN by splitting on commas. In both cases, negative lookbehind is used to make sure that the slashes/commas are not escaped.

Not as pretty, I know. But it's still an one-liner (yay!) and it still allows you to use LINQ further down to handle multiple `OU`s any way you choose to.

Comment: @AndrewCooper: Updated with a regex-enabled version that works. BTW, negative lookbehind is the way to go with the regex here, makes it much more understandable. On the other hand, backward slash hell :/

Comment: You can reduce the backslash hell using verbatim string literals like this:   `Regex.Split(str, @"(?<!\\)/")`